# which one is faster: "insert on duplicate update" OR "update with case"

Tags: mysql-8.0, update

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE t5 (
 col1 VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 col2 int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
 col3 int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
 UNIQUE (col2)
);
```

Records already inside:

```
insert into t5(col1, col2, col3) values 
('872c18ba-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0', 1, 1), 
('823c3d3a-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0', 2, 2);
```

Which of these two queries are expected to perform better:

Query-1:

```
insert into t5(col1, col2, col3) values 
 ('872c18ba-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0', 2, 888), 
 ('823c3d3a-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0', NULL, 999), 
on duplicate key update 
 col2=if(values(col2) IS NULL, col2, values(col2)), 
 col3=if(values(col3) IS NULL, col3, values(col3));
```

Query-2:

```
update t5 set 
 col2=(case col1 when '872c18ba-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0' then 2 END), 
 col3=(case col1 when '872c18ba-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0' then 888 when '823c3d3a-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0' then 999 END) 
where col1 in ('872c18ba-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0', '823c3d3a-35ae-11e9-91a5-88d7f65253d0');
```

Please take note in query-2, the statement is tailored from client side by pruning the NULL value first.

Condition of the table and the frequency the above query is performed as below:

- number of records is in hundreds of thousand
- query is performed once every x-seconds, each with ~150 keys

The objective is to reduce the I/O by not hammering the db with one single query on loop, as well as preventing a deadlock due to query taken too long time (yes, there was some deadlock earlier)

Answer (score 0):

1. `col2=if(values(col2) IS NULL, col2, values(col2))` is equal to `col2=COALESCE(values(col2), col2)`.
2. If ODKU causes `UNIQUE (col2)` violation, the whole query will fail (see fiddle, first query).
3. The queries are not equivalent (second query will set col2=NULL for 1st record, see fiddle).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d17634121835cdf80d46245d908d69cd)

---

Finally:

> which faster: “insert on duplicate update” OR “update with case”

If no errors in queries and data INSERT .. ODKU is faster.

Comment: 3. tested the query and it wont make col2=NULL. it will however update the value with the existing record (kind of update but no change)

Comment: @nyotoarif *3. tested the query and it wont make col2=NULL* See fiddle. Your structure, your data, your queries (minor errors edited). col2 **actually** is set to NULL.

Comment: sorry you were right! tested it again and it updated into NULL. can you please help with giving more detail info why ODKU will perform better?

Comment: @nyotoarif In practice - when stongly 2 strongly existing records strongly updating, no chance to detect the difference in execution time. Ever when you increase the number of updated records the difference will not become detectable I think. But the complexicity of a query will increase.